# Ввод массива построчно

Tags: python, массивы

Нужно написать функцию, которая будет принимать списки чисел и сохранять их в виде массива.
Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
def arra():
    m  = int(input("Введи число строк матрицы: "))
    arr_2d=[]
    for i in range(m):
        arr_2d.append(list(input('Введи строку: ')))
    return arr_2d
```

почему-то выдает arr_2d в виде списка после сплита. Т.е. при вводе, например, трех списков

```
23 34
23 3
23 0
```

происходит выдача:

```
[['2', '3', ' ', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', ' ', '3'], ['2', '3', ' ', '0']]
```

Должно быть

```
[['23', '34'], 
['23','3'], 
['23','0']]
```

Comment: arr_2d.append(input('Введи строку: ').split())

Comment: `list(input('Введи строку: '))` создает список из введенной строки посимвольно. То есть `list('ab12 34') == ['a', 'b', '1', '2', ' ', '3', '4']`, а в вашем случае `list('23 34') == ['2', '3', ' ', '3', '4']`. Чтобы разбить строку на числа стоит использовать `[int(i) for i in input().split()]`. То есть сначала строка разбивается по пробелам, а потом каждая из подстрок приводится к целочисленному типу.